# Server 2012 R2 Shared folder read permissions issue

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

We just migrated a spanned shared volume from a 2003 server to a  2012 Windows Server (migration took place by detaching vmdks from the old vm and attaching them to newer one). This did not effect permissions, I'm just saying it to explain the scenario.

Problem in case is: We have a parent folder called 'Users' where we keep individual subfolders for users' personal data; each user and domain admin has full access to his subfolder. Everyone has read access to the parent folder 'Users' so that everyone can see the list of folders. I've highlighted the setup below

Users (Read access to Everyone)

--User 1 subfolder (Full access user 1)

--User 2 subfolder (Full access user 2)

--User 3 subfolder (Full access user 3)

--User 4 subfolder (Full access user 4)

--User 5 subfolder (Full access user 5)

--User 6 subfolder (Full access user 6)

The problem is when a user open the 'Users' parent folder only their folder is listed when we would like to list all subfolders. Any ideas please ?

Comment: It sounds like Access Bases Enumeration is enabled on the share, that's what I would look at first.

Comment: You need to add List Folder Content on users permissions.

Answer (score 0):

based on this : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(v=ws.10).aspx
you should verify that the users have the "List Folder Contents" attribute on the "Users" foler.
You may have inheritance breaking this, or users in multiple groups with different access rights (the one with less privileges is applied). You can verify each user access right in the "effective permissions" tab.